# Reverse for 'edit_team' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['club_home/edit_team/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Receiving the above error when trying to create a page to update my model using a serializer. Unable to use pk in edit_team view. Any ideas where I am going wrong? Delete button is working fine with the pk not sure why the update is not.

**urls.py**

```
path('teams/', views.TeamInfo.as_view(), name='teams'),
path('delete_team/<int:pk>/', views.delete_team, name='delete_team'),
path('edit_team/<int:pk>/', views.edit_team, name='edit_team'),
```

**teams.html**

```
<div class="team">
<h3>Team Details</h3>
<p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for info in teams %}
<li>{{ info.club_id }}</li>
<li>{{ info.team_name }}</li>
<li>{{ info.manager_name }}</li>
<form action="{% url 'clubs:delete_team' info.pk %}">
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
<form action="{% url 'clubs:edit_team' info.pk %}">
<input type="submit" value="Edit">
```

**edit_team.html**

```
{% extends 'club_main_page.html' %}
{% load rest_framework %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="editteam">
  <h3>Edit Team</h3>
<form action="{% url 'clubs:edit_team' pk=instance.pk %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
     {% render_form serializer %}
<input type="submit" name="" value="Update">
</form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def delete_team(request, pk):
    team = Team.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    team.delete()
    return redirect('clubs:teams')


def edit_team(request, pk):
    instance = Team.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TeamSerializer(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        serializer = TeamSerializer(instance=instance)
        return render(request, 'edit_team.html', {'serializer': serializer})
```

> Trackback: \clubkit\clubs\views.py in edit_pitch
>           return render(request, 'edit_pitch.html', {'serializer': serializer})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you write:

```
<form action="{% url 'clubs:edit_team' pk=instance.pk %}" method="POST">
```

but there is *no* `instance` variable, you pass to the rendering process, you thus should add this one as well, so:

```
def edit_team(request, pk):
    instance = Team.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TeamSerializer(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        serializer = TeamSerializer(instance=instance)
        return render(
            request,
            'edit_team.html',
            {'serializer': serializer, 'instance': instance})
```

I'm not sure however, if redirecting to `/` is a good idea, certainly not if the `serializer` is *not* valid. In that case, one typically wants to render the page again, but with the errors. Therefore it is probably also a better idea to [make use of forms [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Comment: Hi Willem, I tried this but still receiving the same error. Thanks for the feedback on the redirection just aiming to get it working first. Would it just be best to accomplish this using a form, just would have liken to get it working with the serializer as I know already how to do it with a form. Just want to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the PK to the template, so it can't be used to generate the URL there. Change the last line of your view:

```
return render(request, 'edit_team.html', {''pk': pk, serializer': serializer})
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, if I add this in how will I apply it to my form:                                    
  <form action="{% url 'clubs:edit_team' pk=instance.pk %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
         {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Update">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Would have liken to figure this out using the serializer. But just went with a form here solution just in case any one needs it:

```
def edit_team(request, pk):
instance = Team.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TeamForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('clubs:teams')
    else:
        return redirect('clubs:teams')
else:
    form = TeamForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'edit_team.html', {'form': form,
                                              'instance': instance})
```

Then in the template:

```
{% extends 'club_main_page.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Edit Pitch</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class="container">
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```